# .Bat script to open telnet, enter login and password and carry out actions

Tags: cmd, telnet

I need to write a script to run telnet, enter login and password, carry out steps and enter a number then press enter at the end.

The following takes me to login:

```bash
@echo off
Telnet 12.122.444.30
```

Anyone who wants to take the time to help, would be appreciated; I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Create a text file with answer
Sample response.txt
username
password
number

execute telnet redirecting input
telnet 12.122.444.30 < response.txt

Regards